# Error in GEE: Property of feature is missing

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, random-forest

I am trying to do a supervised classification in GEE, I tried the same code over one area of interest and it worked. However, when I combined both sites, an error occurred "Property '0_SR_B2' of feature '0_0000000000000006f3d6' is missing".

Can someone provide some insights about the reason?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/510d763aa54c0ab86b447f6cc1f80f54

```
//                   ///////Landsat data/////
// Define a function that scales and masks Landsat 8 surface reflectance images.
function prepSrL8(image) {
  // Develop masks for unwanted pixels (fill, cloud, cloud shadow).
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var getFactorImg = function(factorNames) {
    var factorList = image.toDictionary().select(factorNames).values();
    return ee.Image.constant(factorList);
  };
  var scaleImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_MULT_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var offsetImg = getFactorImg([
    'REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_.|TEMPERATURE_ADD_BAND_ST_B10']);
  var scaled = image.select('SR_B.|ST_B10').multiply(scaleImg).add(offsetImg);

  // Replace original bands with scaled bands and apply masks.
  return image.addBands(scaled, null, true)
    .updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask);
}


// Make a cloud-free Landsat 8 surface reflectance composite.
var dates =[ 
  strong text// ee.DateRange('2020-01-16', '2020-02-01'),
  // ee.DateRange('2020-02-01', '2020-02-16'),
  // ee.DateRange('2020-02-16', '2020-03-01'),
  // ee.DateRange('2020-03-01', '2020-03-16'),
  // ee.DateRange('2020-03-16', '2020-04-01'),
  // ee.DateRange('2020-04-01', '2020-04-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-04-16', '2020-05-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-01', '2020-05-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-16', '2020-06-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-01', '2020-06-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-16', '2020-07-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-01', '2020-07-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-16', '2020-08-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-01', '2020-08-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-16', '2020-09-01'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-01', '2020-09-16'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-16', '2020-10-01'),
 // ee.DateRange('2020-10-01', '2020-10-16'),
  //ee.DateRange('2020-10-16', '2020-11-01'),
  // ee.DateRange('2020-11-01', '2020-11-16'),
  // ee.DateRange('2020-11-16', '2020-12-01'),
  // ee.DateRange('2020-12-01', '2020-12-16'),
  // ee.DateRange('2020-12-16', '2021-01-01'),
  
]
//var bands = ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5',
            // 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']
             
var addNDVI = function(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5','SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDWI = function(img) {
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3', 'SR_B5']).rename('NDWI')
  return img.addBands(ndwi)
}

// //EVI
var addEVI= function(image){
  var evi= image.expression(
              '2.5*(NIR-RED)/(NIR+6*RED-7.5*BLUE+10000)',{
              NIR:image.select('SR_B5'),
              RED:image.select('SR_B4'),
              BLUE:image.select('SR_B2'),
            }).float().rename('EVI')
  return image.addBands(evi)
}

var list = dates.map(function(range) {
  return ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
      .filterDate(ee.DateRange(range))
      .filter(ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.bounds(Egypt),
    ee.Filter.bounds(ROI_Eth)
  ))
  //.filterBounds(ROI)
      .map(addNDVI)
      .map(addNDWI)
      .map(addEVI)
      .select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI','NDWI'])
      //.select(['NDVI','NDWI','EVI'])
      //.mean()
      .median()
      .rename(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5','SR_B6', 'SR_B7','NDVI','NDWI'])
      //.rename(['NDVI','NDWI','EVI'])
});

/////create a stacked layer from the landsat image///
//***first prepare area to clip the stacked image on**//
var clipped = Egypt.merge(ROI_Eth);

//**now create the stacked image**//
var stacked = ee.ImageCollection(list).toBands().clip(clipped);
Map.addLayer(stacked, {bands: ["3_NDVI", "5_NDVI", "8_NDVI"]}, 'Stacked', false)
Map.centerObject(ROI,10);
//print(stacked);

//                         /////****Preparing training data****////
                        
                        
// // // //Generate 2000 random pt sample of Ethopia& 3000 for Egypt///////
var random1 = VP_Ethopia.randomColumn().sort('random').limit(2000);
//print(random1);

var random2 = VP_Egypt.randomColumn().sort('random').limit(3000);
//print(random2);

var combined= random1.merge(random2);

// // Place the collections in a new collection.
var combined = ee.FeatureCollection([random1,random2]);

// // Flatten the collection to create a new feature collection with all the features.
var flattened = combined.flatten();

// // Sample the image data at the random points
var training = stacked.reduceRegions({
  collection: flattened,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  scale: 30
});
//print(training);
// Map.addLayer(training, {}, 'points', false);


// //How balanced are the training data?
//print(training.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), ["RASTERVALU"]));

// Filter out values of -9999 from your training feature collection
var training = training.filter(ee.Filter.neq('RASTERVALU', -9999));

/// Filter out the null property values and try again.
var trainingNoNulls = training.filter(
  ee.Filter.notNull(stacked.bandNames().add("RASTERVALU"))
);
//print(trainingNoNulls.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), ["RASTERVALU"]));


////split the training data for traininig and validation/////
var sample=trainingNoNulls.randomColumn();
var split=0.7;
var training_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split));
var validation_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split));

//           //////////////Train RF classifier//////////////

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'RASTERVALU',
  inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),
});
var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified');
Map.addLayer(classified.randomVisualizer(),{},'classification', true);


// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your time-periods contain no images for some locations.

You thought you filtered them out, but you didn't.  You're training with the collection `training` but the filtered/randomized collection is called `training_sample`.

You might debug this by printing the collection you're using in the training call, right above that, with a filter the pulls out just the feature that's being complained about in the error:

```
print(training.filter("system:index == '0_0000000000000006f3d6'"))
```

and working your way back up to to the `notNull` filter, printing that feature along the way.

Comment: Oh, thank you @ Noel. I really do not know how I mixed between training and training_sample. Regarding the missed images in my time period, is there is a way to deal with this? I also increased my time period to include the whole year, but some tiles are still missing!